# Finding probability of finding alternative balls

Tags: probability

A bag contain $5$ white balls and $4$ black balls. One ball is drawn at a time . 
What is the probability that the balls drawn will be alternately white and black ?

My try :

i though $p(W)$ is white ball and $p(B)$ is black ball

This event is not independent , its dependent.

So used the formula

$p(aleternative) = P(W)*P(B|A)$

$= 5/9 *1/2$

$= 5/18$

But this is wrong answer .. Guide me where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how many balls are drawn. We assume that all $9$ are.

There are $\binom{9}{4}$ equally likely positions that the black balls can be in.

Of these, precisely $1$ gives us alternating white and black.

So the required probavility is $1/\binom{9}{4}$.

Comment: why you used only black ball ?

Comment: Once we decide where the black balls go, the position of the white balls is determined. If you like, you can call the number of ways $\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{5}$. But $\binom{5}{5}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of first white ball is $\frac{5}{9}$

The probability of second ball being black given first ball was white is $\frac{4}{8}$

The probability of third ball being white given previous two balls were white and black is $\frac{4}{7}$

Thus you can go on for the 4th ball being black given the previous 3 balls are W,B,W is $\frac{3}{6}$

Go on till the last ball and then multiply. You would see the pattern is $\frac{5\cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 }$